# Why can't my server connect MYSQL database when I can access and ssh it?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I'm setting up my server and I can connect to the DB using `mysql -u root -p` and by ssh from outside  the server.

But I am getting    `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` when I start my server.

I have no clue why this is happening. I am able to ssh and connect  with the same password without issue. On my server I am using port 3360 and host 127.0.0.1.

I tried reinstalling mysql, changing passwords and using the remote server IP but nothing works. I want my server to have access to the database

Comment: Can you connect through an SSH tunnel?

Comment: Your password may contain special characters that aren't parsed correctly when using the connection string

Comment: Also, if your password contains a `$`, make sure it's single quoted, or PHP will try to interpolate a variable that doesn't exist

Comment: @Cid Thank you, it was a special character. I sometimes forget since im using a password manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check Password
2. Check if the User root is allowed to connect
3. Check the MySQL server configuration file (usually located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf) for the bind-address parameter. Make sure it is set to 127.0.0.1 or localhost
4. Check Firewall Settings on spesifically port 3360
5. Check Error Log in the MySQL data directory,

Maybe this helps

Comment: The password had a special character. Thanks for the idea to check it!